# Android Studio - Dropbox sync across Windows and Mac

Tags: android, windows, macos, android-studio, dropbox

I have a Windows machine at home and a macbook that I travel with. I want to develop my android app on both machines so have created project files hosted on Dropbox.

The project was created on Windows, and when I try to import the project on my macbook I get a bunch of errors. I get these when trying to run the app as well:

```
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/Users/path_to_app/app/src/main/res/dtplugin/deployJava1.dll

Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/Users/path_to_app/app/src/main/res/plugin2/msvcr100.dll

Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/Users/path_to_app/app/src/main/res/server/classes.jsa
```

I'm guessing the way windows and osx handle the build process differ, but what is the correct way to sync a project between the 2 platforms, thus avoiding errors like the above? As it stands, I can't build or test my app on the macbook at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not sure the correct way to handle this, but it turns out that if I create the project on my Mac, I can build/run the project on both OSX and Windows no problem (besides resetting some local paths, which android studio does for me).

The same is not true going the other way - creating projects on windows results in not being able to do anything with it in OSX